# Adding items to DataGrid on Key down WPF, bad performance?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, datagrid

My application is about this : I got sql database with products inside, on main `Window.xaml` there is `DataGrid` and `TextBox`.

Application is very simple(*explained below*):

User should look for product by entering product code in `TextBox` and pressing enter, if product with that code exist in database, it will be added to `DataGrid`! And after that user can decide if he's going to delete some items from datagrid, or to print them all etc..

Here is how it looks, I did little bit drawing in paint :)

[image]

My issue starts here:

When I am adding items from database to my `DataGrid` it's working somehow slow, I mean it is not fast as it should be, It's really possible to feel there is little bit of delay when item is being aded to a `DataGrid`.

I thought I did everything as it should be, but probably I did not, and I guess there must be some issue with performance, or my code is bad!

Now I will post my code, so If you could guys give me advice how to speed it up or maybe suggest me what I could do better, please do it, I would really appreaciate that because obliviously I am doing it wrong, *maybe I am not binding data to a `DataGrid` as it should or something else*, but I don't want my applicataion to be slow, especially because it is really simple app..

Here is my code:

```
//I need to add new item from database to my DataGrid when user press Enter 
private void txtCode_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            {
        //Here I am making sure that I will not look for empty string in my database
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCode.Text.Trim()))
                {
            //Here I am looking for product in my database with code that user entered 
                    Article product = ArticlesController.GetProductByProductCode(txtCode.Text.Trim());

                    if (product!= null)
                    {
                        ProductTemporary tempProduct= new ProductTemporary();

                        tempProduct.ArticleCode = product.ArticleCode;
                        tempProduct.Price = product.Price;
                        tempProduct.Quantity = 1;
                        tempProduct.ArticleId = product.Id;
                        tempProduct.ArticleTitle = product.Title;
                        tempProduct.TotalAmount = (tempProduct.Quantity * tempProduct.Price);

            //Here I'm adding item from database to Temp Table in case computer turns off, so when user log in back he can still find items he searched for before
                        var lastInserted = ProductsTempController.InsertNewTempProduct(tempProduct);

                        currentlyDataGridItems.Add(lastInserted);

                        dtgProductItems.ItemsSource = null;
                        dtgProductItems.ItemsSource = currentlyDataGridItems;

                        txtCode.Text = "";
                        txtCode.Focus();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Product with next code:" + txtCode.Text + " does not exist.", "Search by product code", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                        txtCode.Text = "";
                        txtCode.Focus();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So I'm wondering what is wrong with this code, why I must feel delay when I am adding item to my DataGrid, I believed it takes time to search for product in database, but acctualy I removed all but 5 products so it should work really fast, in fact it is very simple action :

**find item in database, insert it to a temp table, add it to a datagrid**

But somehow it does not work fast as expected,
whatever, thanks a lot guys and cheers!

Comment: nice question about performance, I hope someone will answer to it how to improve that, because I am also very curious about that!

Comment: `dtgProductItems.ItemsSource = null;` Why do you do this?

Comment: @Emad because when user add item to a datagrid I want to show it to him immediatelly, something like refreshing datagrid.. setting source to null then adding it again but with new item inside..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all data grid is a heavy and slow control even in perfect implementations because it has many things to do but, your problem is constantly removing and adding all the element again this causes the rendering to happen from beginning.

What you should do is to use WPF `ObservableCollection<T>` to hold your list. Observable collections have this property that when you add or remove an element to them all the bindings will automatically get notified and UI gets updated (with only what needs to be updated).

In a better approach I add items to UI collection only in predefined intervals like every second this way if user presses the button 10 times in a row your UI only gets updated once with all new information.

To do this first define a list:

```
var result = new ObservableCollection<ProductTemporary>();
```

Then set the list to be source of items for your grid

```
dtgProductItems.ItemsSource = result;
```

And finally when you want to change it just change the `result`

```
result.Add(lastInserted);
```

On final tip for you is do non UI jobs in another thread to keep the UI responsive.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: seems like it is faster after doing it on this way, but how could I load my ProductTemporary to my ObservableCollection ? Because in case somehow computer shut down I need to keep my items there when user turns on computer and log in,so I need something like this:  ObservableCollection<ProductTemporary> result = ProductsTempController.Instance.SelectAll(); but after that I'm facing an error :/

Comment: You should create ObservableCollection from your list like this: `new ObservableCollection<ProductTemporary>(ProductsTempController.Instance.SelectAll());`

Comment: Aha, I understand, and what about that when I AM REMOVING item from datagrid, than I should call result.Remove(lastInserted); ?

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` is and implementation of `ICollection<T>` which means it works just like `List<T>`

Comment: check for my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581098/removing-item-from-list-which-is-source-to-datagrid-causes-triggering-selection