# Removing item from list which is source to datagrid causes triggering selection changed on the same grid

Tags: c#, wpf, list, events, datagrid

I have a

```
 ObservableCollection<ProductTemporary> result = ProductsTempController.Instance.SelectAll();
```

Which is source to my datagrid, and by pressing DEL while item in datagrid is selected I am removing it:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
{
    if (dataGridProducts.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ProductTemporary tempItem = (ProductTemporary)dataGridProducts.SelectedItem;
        ProductTemporaryController.Instance.Delete(tempItem.Id);
        dataGridProducts.Remove(tempItem);
        UpdateTotalAmount();
    }
}
```

Issue starts here:

```
 dataGridProducts.Remove(tempItem);
```

After this line dataGridProducts selection changed is triggered, so I'm losing focus on my grid items, and I need that focus in case I WANT TO remove all items by selecting just one and keeping DEL pressed.

***So how could I avoid triggering dataGridProducts selection changed event after changing its source ( dataGridProducts.Remove(tempItem) ), I tried with `e.Handled=true`, like this:***

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
{
    e.Handled=true;
    if (dataGridProducts.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ProductTemporary tempItem = (ProductTemporary)dataGridProducts.SelectedItem;
        ProductTemporaryController.Instance.Delete(tempItem.Id);
        dataGridProducts.Remove(tempItem);
    }
}
```

But it did not help me..

Thanks guys
Cheers

**AFTER mm8 suggestion I made EDIT:**7

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
            {
                if (dataGridProducts.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    ProductTemporary  tempItem = (ProductTemporary )dataGridProducts.SelectedItem;
                    ProductTemporaryController.Instance.Delete(tempItem.Id);
                }
                UpdateTotalAmount();
            }
```

But somehow everytime I delete item in datagrid, lets say I have 2 items in datagrid, and when I press DEL key it will be gone from UI but in code behind UpdateTotalAmount method is called and in my `ObservableCollection<ProductTemporary> result` there are still two items so it will show me total amount of two items instead of one..

Here is my methods code:

```
public void UpdateTotalAmount()
        {
            double sum = 0;

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDouble(item.TotalAmount);
            }

            btnTotal.Content = string.Format("{0:0.00}", sum) + " " + EUR;


        }
```

How could I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you explicitly remove the item from the `ObservableCollection`? The `DataGrid` control does this for you so you just have to remove the item from the database.

Try to handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event for the `DataGrid` like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridProducts" PreviewKeyDown="dg_KeyDown" ... />
```

---

```
private void dg_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        if (dataGridProducts.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            ProductTemporary tempItem = (ProductTemporary)dataGridProducts.SelectedItem;
            ProductTemporaryController.Instance.Delete(tempItem.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

In other words you could just remove the `dataGridProducts.Remove(tempItem);` line from your event handler.

Comment: I explicitly remove item from `ObservableCollection` because later I am looping that  `ObservableCollection` which is also source to my datagrid because it contains product informations like title, price etc, and I am also showing on my window.xaml total amount - sum of prices, so when I delete item from datagrid I acctualy need to remove it also from `ObservableCollection` because I need to update total amount of products in my datagrid.. and I'm doing that as I said by looping my `ObservableCollection` and suming prices...

Comment: There is one solution, to delete item from database, and after that when I am updating total amount, to call `ObservableCollection<ProductTemporary> result = ProductsTempController.Instance.SelectAll();` and like this I would get updated items from database, and I would get correct sum, but I think it is bad approach because I am calling GET ALL TEMP PRODUCTS every time when I delete item from dataGrid..

Comment: The point is that the DataGrid removes the item from the ObservableCollection for you automatically when the delete key is pressed. This is built in functionality. Did you even try my suggestion? It works wonders for me.

Comment: Yes your suggestion works perfect! But I have problem with that when I remove item from UI and call my method for prices updating there are still two items in ObservableCollection<ProductTemporary> result, please check for my EDIT please. And one more time thank you a lot, you are awesome!

Comment: Could you please ask a new question if you have another issue? By the way, did you check my suggestion of how to programmatically highlight a row in the DataGrid?

Comment: I will check it right after I fix this! in cca 15-20mins, well I will post new question in a minut then.

Comment: its here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586271/issue-with-removing-item-from-observablecollection-i-am-doing-something-wrong

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the best bet is to set the SelectedIndex of the datagrid to the index of the next item. Actually it would be the index of the existing item, as by removing it from the collection the next item would assume its index.

Comment: that might work but than my selected item/index wont be highlighted like it is when user clicks on it..

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard behavior for a list to loose it's selected item upon delete exactly for the opposite reason than this:

> I WANT TO remove all items by selecting just one and keeping DEL pressed

It will be a bad approach to allow user to remove two items in a row by pressing delete button twice so there are two things you can do:

1. Newer and best approach is to have a clear button somewhere so that when you want to remove all items at once you are able to
2. Handle multiple selection in your grid. And by handle I mean if you have any process that requires the selected item of the grid. Otherwise just set datagrids selection mode to multiple