# Issue with removing item from ObservableCollection, I am doing something wrong

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, datagrid

I have a DataGrid which contains informations about products, like NAME and PRICE,
Items could be added or removed from DataGrid by Pressing DEL Key down (Remove case).

I am using ObservableCollection as DataGrid source, and it looks like this:

```
ObservableCollection<ProductTemporary> result = ProductsTempController.Instance.SelectAll();
```

Also there is button on my Window which is keeping sum of my product's prices updated all the time, when item is added sum is increased, when item is removed sum is decreased and stuffs like that..

In my case I have issue with removing items from my Collection, well, as I said I am doing it by pressing DEL key so here is my code:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
{
    if (dataGridProducts.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ProductTemporary tempItem = (ProductTemporary)dataGridProducts.SelectedItem;
        ProductTemporaryController.Instance.Delete(tempItem.Id);

        UpdateTotalAmount();
    }
}


public void UpdateTotalAmount()
{
    double sum = 0;
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToDouble(item.TotalAmount);
    }
    btnTotal.Content = string.Format("{0:0.00}", sum) + " " + EUR;
}
```

As it is possible to see, first I am removing item from database, ObservableCollection will take care to remove it from UI, but I am still having issue in this case:

Lets say there are 2 items on datagrid, when users press del, item will be removed from database but method  UpdateTotalAmount(); will be called right after that, and in my Collection there will be two items and I will see incorect Total sum..

So probably I am not doing this  UpdateTotalAmount calling on right place or smth like that,

I also thought about this solution:

In stored procedure which is removing item I could send back sum of total items from database, so in that case I dont need to loop any collection to do smth like that, but I think it is not good practice?

Thanks guys,
Cheers

Comment: FWIW this kind of stuff tends to be easier when using MVVM

Comment: @BradleyDotNET FWIW?

Comment: For What Its Worth

Comment: @Roxy'Pro, Remove selected item from the source object not the control. The observable collection should raise property changed even with will update the control

Comment: @Nkosi than event selection changed on datagrid will be fired and I will lose focus on product items, and lets say I don't use mouse :D

Comment: @Roxy'Pro, Obviously selection will change, you are removing an item

Comment: @Nkosi with this approach right now there will be allways focus on some of items in my datagrid, so I can hold del key to remove them all, and in case you said I could remove only 1 item and I would lose focus than I should click again on items in my datagrid etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the `Delete` and `UpdateTotalAmount` methods in your event handler you could handle the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection` and remove the item from the database when it is removed from the collection:

```
ObservableCollection<ProductTemporary> result = new ObservableCollection<ProductTemporary>();//ProductsTempController.Instance.SelectAll();
result.CollectionChanged += (ss, ee) => 
{
    if(ee.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove 
        && ee.OldItems !=null && ee.OldItems.Count > 0)
    {
        ProductTemporary removedItem = ee.OldItems[0] as ProductTemporary;
        ProductTemporaryController.Instance.Delete(removedItem.Id);
        UpdateTotalAmount();
    }
};
```

Then you don't need any `PreviewKeyDown` event handler at all.

Comment: @mm8 this is great answer! but could you explain it more detailed line by line please, it works perfect but I am wondering what is happening really!

Comment: and one more thing, on this way you did it I could not for example ask user if he is sure he will delete that item? for example MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete selected item"); in that case I must look again for PreviewKeyDown event handler?

Comment: You could show the MessageBox in the event handler but still remove the item in the CollectionChanged event if the users confirms. CollectionChanged is an event that fires whenever an item is added or removed from the collection.

Comment: in case I want to delete item only on PreviewKeyDown event handler when user press Del Key should I just move code you posted into Del Key Down event handler? Or what ? I mean I want to have control when collection is changed (only on Key.Down Delete) ?

Comment: If you want to something only when the DELETE key is pressed, handling the PreviewKeyDown event sounds like a good idea.